# F# further requirement for finding unique array of tuples

Tags: f#

I have 4 arrays of different data. For the first array of string, I want to delete the duplicate element and get the results of array of unique tuples with 4 elements.
For example, let's say the arrays are:

```
let dupA1 = [| "A"; "B"; "C"; "D"; "A" |]
let dupA2 = [| 1; 2; 3; 4; 1 |]
let dupA3 = [| 1.0M; 2.0M; 3.0M; 4.0M; 1.0M |]
let dupA4 = [| 1L; 2L; 3L; 4L; 1L |]
```

I want the result to be:

```
let uniqueArray = [| ("A", 1, 1.0M, 1L); ("B", 2, 2.0M, 2L); ("C", 3, 3.0M, 3L); ("D",4,
```

Thanks to abatishchev for his great code, now I have this answer:

```
let zip4 a (b : _ []) (c : _ []) (d : _ []) =
    Array.init (Array.length a) (fun i -> a.[i], b.[i], c.[i], d.[i])
let uniqueArray = zip4 dupA1 dupA2 dupA3 dupA4 |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toArray
```

However, further more, I want to find the result of each array from the unique array.

```
let uniqueArray = [| ("A", 1, 1.0M, 1L); ("B", 2, 2.0M, 2L); ("C", 3, 3.0M, 3L); ("D",4, 4.0M, 4L) |]
```

I want the following 4 arrays from uniqeArray:

```
let uniqA1  = [| "A"; "B"; "C"; "D" |]
let uniqA2 = [| 1; 2; 3; 4 |]
let uniqA3 = [| 1.0M; 2.0M; 3.0M; 4.0M |]
let uniqA4 = [| 1L; 2L; 3L; 4L |]
```

I tried the following code:

```
let [| uniqA1, uniqA2, uniqA3, uniqA4 |] = uniqueArray
```

First, I get the compiler warning:

> Warning    1
>   Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '`[|_; _|]`' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

After I used `#nowarn "25"`, during the run time, I got the following error:

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.MatchFailureException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.MatchFailureException' occurred in Program.exe
```

Please help me with the further requirements.

Comment: If you are done with your previous question, you should mark an answer as correct.

Comment: abatishchev didn't write that code. It's @Ramon Snir who wrote the code. Please give credits to whom helped you.

Comment: Hi,
Than you for your feed back, I could make mistake for the wrong credit, I will change it later; but I can not see how I can mark the question as answered.
Please give me some directions.
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You now need `unzip4`:

```
let unzip4 arr =
    let a = Array.zeroCreate (Array.length arr)
    let b = Array.zeroCreate (Array.length arr)
    let c = Array.zeroCreate (Array.length arr)
    let d = Array.zeroCreate (Array.length arr)
    arr
    |> Array.iteri (fun i (x, y, z, w) ->
        a.[i] <- x
        b.[i] <- y
        c.[i] <- z
        d.[i] <- w)
    a, b, c, d
```

Then you can do:

```
> let uniqA1, uniqA2, uniqA3, uniqA4 = unzip4 uniqueArray;;

val uniqA4 : int64 [] = [|1L; 2L; 3L; 4L|]
val uniqA3 : decimal [] = [|1.0M; 2.0M; 3.0M; 4.0M|]
val uniqA2 : int [] = [|1; 2; 3; 4|]
val uniqA1 : string [] = [|"A"; "B"; "C"; "D"|]
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for your great code, it works very well.
However, I still don't know how to mark the answer as correct.
If I know I will do it and credit to your work.
Thanks again for your timely help!
John

Comment: To the left of the post, there are up/down arrows and below them an outlined v button. Click on the button (and on the up arrow, if you wish to say the answer was good!) to accept the answer.